# How much does the clock drift for the Arduino Pro Mini board?

Tags: arduino, atmega, clock-speed

How much does the clock drift (at most) for the Arduino Pro Mini board?

I don't need to correct it on the board, just need to know the specifications, such that I can take the necessary precautions in the cloud with data sampled by the board.

The board is based on the ATmega328, but I guess the clock precision depends on the external crystal as well.

To do an estimate, I've counted pulses from a signal generator Rigol DG1022 and used that as a reference. With a frequency of 100Hz (square wave, 0-5V) this should give 6000 pulses/min. I sum up the counts in packages of 5 seconds on the a
Arduino.

This chip is pretty bad (up to 410ppm deviation). Other chips are ranging from -160ppm to 50ppm deviations.

I don't have enough rep to make all the above links links correctly. Can someone edit? Or I will do myself, when I get the rep. for it.

[image]
[image: Clock drift]

Comment: So you already did some tests on your own and figured out that the numbers vary, so what exactly is it that you want?

Comment: I want to find out how to obtain the _theoretical_ specs for the Arduino Pro Mini. I couldn't find it in the datasheets. Even if I've made some tests, it helps me being confident in my limits. I'm very dependent on what the limits are, as I'm correcting the skewed measurements in the cloud, once the ,easurements are uploaded.

Comment: Then find out what determines those specs. That depends on how the clock is implemented on the board, you tell us **nothing** about that. The Atmega MCUs have a build-in clockgenerator which is quite inaccurate and has a lot of drift. For that there will be specifications in the ATmega's datasheet. But very likely your board uses a crystal or a resonator and not the internal oscillator.

Comment: @Clausen: I am pretty confident that ardunios dont specify these things, but maybe people on ardunio.se know more. very likely they whack in whatever crystal was on the shenzen market today

Comment: Almost any crystal is good to 50-100ppm in the default Pierce oscillator configuration. If it's a resonator, think more like 0.25 to 0.5% (5000ppm) initial accuracy and substantial drift with temperature. If it's using the internal oscillator- well read the datasheet but probably somewhat worse than the resonator, after calibration, with more drift. I believe most of the cheap nano boards use resonators.

Comment: Ok, so it ALL comes down to the crystal? I did not know that. I'm sorry. I will look into that. Thank to those with constructive comments. They could be answers!?

Comment: @FakeMoustache I think "Ardiuno Pro Mini" should identify the device sufficiently, although the datasheet could have been included in the question: https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/Arduino-Pro-Mini-schematic.pdf

Comment: @Clausen Are you aware that the actual clock frequency will vary with time, voltage, and temperature as well?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your method for measurement? The Arduino is counting pulses? What's its time reference for those 5 second intervals?

Comment: Another approach: Take a cheap GPS receiver, connect its 1pps output to an input capture pin of the AVR and let the corresponding timer run at F_CPU, i.e. maximum speed. This lets you directly read the the number of clock cycles for one second in the input capture ISR with the best accuracy you can get.

Comment: @JimmyB *I think "Ardiuno Pro Mini" should identify the device sufficiently* Have you looked on eBay how many versions there are of "Arduino Pro Mini" ? I bet you haven't otherwise you would not say that that name alone should identify the device.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Yet, none of those variants uses the internal RC clock or a resonator...

Comment: I had originally included a lot of links to external resources, but my low rep only let me include 2 links. I'm a big fan of well-resourced questions, but I couldn't...
@JimmyB I know it will vary, I just wanted the limits. In the cloud I will continuously adapt the period.
My method was this: Assume the signal generator was precise, and let the arduino time the intervals. That way I KNOW that there should på 500 counts per interval. If there are more, the clock is running slow, if fewer, it's running faster.

Comment: Ok, that's what I imagined. How do you compensate for the low resolution of 1/500, i.e. 2000ppm?

Comment: @JimmyB I average over a longer period, e.g. a few minutes.